# MVC3 model instead model ... can't see when posting to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, formcollection

I have an order model (shown below)

```
public class Order
    {
        //[Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Order Date")]
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ProductSelection ProductSelection { get; set; }

        public virtual ShippingDetails ShippingDetails { get; set; }

        public virtual BillingDetails BillingDetails { get; set; }

        public virtual CardDetails CardDetails { get; set; }

        public virtual AccountUser AccountUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see is made up of a set of other models for example ProductSelection (shown below).

```
public class ProductSelection
    {
        public int SimulatorId { get; set; }

        public string VersionNumber { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Quantity")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Total Price")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

The issue I am having is when I post to the Controller which has a parameter of Order, I am unable to obtain any of the values from the sub-models (for example Order.ProductSelection.SimulatorId.)

Any ideas why this isn't working as I having to currently use FormCollection which isn't ideal and better messy.

Looking forward to replies

Steve

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why are your child objects marked as `virtual`?

Comment: Not sure, should they be marked as public?

Comment: Maybe try making them just `public`. I might be going out on a limb here by saying that it could be affecting how the ModelBinder binds your posted data to the Action's argument.

Comment: when you have the properties marked as virtual entity framework use lazy loading

Answer (score 1):

1) Silly question but just to make sure....Do you preserve values of your sub model on the view(In the form as hidden or any other input type,make sure name of your hidden are same as your properties name in the model) or in the query string.
Before giving you fully loaded model, model binder looks at different places to load your model like your form collection,rout data and query string
If you are not preserving them in any of these places then model binder has no way to find those values and give you loaded values on controller action.
Basics.. http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx

2)Your example model seems fine but make sure all properties of your sub model have public access modifier and they must have set in their property declaration.
--->I had same issue before because I had private access modifier for set on those properties and I wasted whole day to figure that out.

3)If nothing works(hope that's not the case) then at last you can write your own model binder.
Here is the good post if you decide to head in that direction
http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/

This is my first post (under my account) and it feels really good to participate..!!

Comment: One more link.. http://forums.asp.net/p/1559541/3846605.aspx  (Silly..!! SO didn't allow me to add more than 2 links.)

Comment: Hi Amit,

Many thanks for the detailed reply.

Regarding the views I have an Order\Index.cshtml file which is made of a JQuery accordion, each section contains a partial view (made up of a specific sub-model E.g. ProductSelection)

So I need to store all values (of the sub models) as hidden fields in the Order\Index.cshtml file and then I will be able to access them in the controller using Order.ProductSelection.Quantity.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to store all values in the Index.cshtml. If you are passing sub model in partials then you can keep them as hidden in your partials and render partial inside your form. This way you will have more readability in your Views.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply ForeignAttribute on the `ProductSelection` property which points the primary key of the `ProductSelection` class:

```
[ForeignKey("SimulatorId")]
public virtual ProductSelection ProductSelection { get; set; }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You could replace the ForeignKeyAttribute with RequiredAttribute which will mark the relation as required and generate ON DELETE CASCADE in the database.

Comment: What so have the SimulatorId attribute in each sub-model and then use ForeignKey on each of the models within Order?

Comment: This is the way to define the relation between Order and ProductSelection class. Here in the ForeignKeyAttribute constructor you should use the name of the primary property of the reference class.

Comment: Ok well for each sub-model I am using OrderId

[ForeignKey("OrderId")]
public virtual ProductSelection ProductSelection { get; set; }

Comment: But does this mean that the Order record in the database will still contain the values from the sub models?

Comment: If the attribute is placed on a foreign key property it represents the name of the associated navigation property. Otherwise (on navigation property)- the name of the associated foreign key.

Comment: I am getting the following error message - System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ProductSelection' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Comment: This means that you need primary key for this type. Just append the primary key property of the type with KeyAttribute.

Comment: Oh right so a unique key per sub-model and then a foreign key of "OrderId" as well?

Comment: For the inverse property - yes.